# Как организовать многоканальное использование бота Telegram?

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram-bot

При одновременном использовании бота разными людьми он работает поочередно.

С начала обрабатывает запрос одного, после второго.

Если это простые команды, то этого незаметно, но есть команды, в которые прописаны скрипты для выполнения, и вот пока этот скрипт не отработает, другую команду не обработает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить, чтобы разные люди могли одновременно отправлять ему команды?

Бот на python.

Нашел так:

```
import threading
theVar = 1
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run ( self ):
        global theVar
def listener(messages):
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['script1'])
    def handle_script1_request(message):
        ip = message.text.split()[-1]
            result = ssh.get_script1(ip)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)
        theVar = theVar + 1
for x in xrange ( 20 ):
    MyThread().start()
```

Как подогнать код под все запросы, которые у меня есть, для одновременного использования разным количеством людей?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы запускаете скрипт у себя на компьютере, то никак, вроде. Если вы запускаете его на сервере, и у вас есть домен, по которому можно обращаться к вашему серверу, то можно использовать [вебхуки](https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter4.html), запустив несколько процессов бота, слушающих один адрес.

Comment: что значит _несколько процессов_? несколько инстансов?

Comment: @Anatol несколько воркеров, которые обрабатывают входящие запросы. Например через UWSGI

Comment: хорошо бы развернуть ответ, дополнить деталями